# Collect user input in Servlet and return at the same point to continue program: Java

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications

I have a web application in Java that performs title matching.

The `Servlet` is the controller and in one of the methods of the `Servlet`, I am comparing two list of titles. The first list is in a `HashMap` and the second is from a query `ResultSet`.

What I want to do is to automatically match those with same title and give the user the option to confirm the ones with some similarities (business logic). Basically, I need to get user input and then return at the same point to continue.

I tried `JOptionPane` dialog box and it didn't work. 
Now I am trying to forward to another HTML page to get user input and then return to the `Servlet`.

Below is the `Servlet` code:

```
while (Querylist.next()) {
    String title = Querylist.getString(1).trim().toLowerCase();

    if (MyMap.containsKey(title))
    {
    // confirm match
    } else 
    {
        //some title2 is like title
        request.setAttribute("Title1", title);
        request.setAttribute("Title2", title2);
        RequestDispatcher view =   request.getRequestDispatcher("TitleMatch.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);  
        ResultMatch= request.getParameter("ResultMatch");
        if (ResultMatch.equals("YES"))
        {
           // confirm match
        }
    }

}
```

HTML Page:

```
<B> <%= request.getAttribute("Title1")%></B>
<B> <%= request.getAttribute("Title2")%></B>
<FORM method="get" action="DataMerge">
    <input type = "radio" name="MatchResult" value="YES" /> YES
    <input type = "radio" name="MatchResult" value="NO" checked/>NO
    <button type = "submit"   formaction="DataMerge" > <b>CONFIRM</b>
</FORM>
```

EDIT: the loop works and I'm having a java.lang.IllegalStateException Exception.
Does anyone can help to figure out how to do that efficiently in plain Java?

I searched all over SO and haven't found something similar. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to reconsider your approach as there are number of fundamental problems with the code you have written. For example:

1. The while loop test it not correct. Assuming that you are using an Iterator then the test should be list.hasNext();
2. The if test is nested and incorrect. You cannot use the identifier `Map` as it is the name of the class, you should use the name of the map object.
3. If the loop worked the view.forward(request, response); would result in an java.lang.IllegalStateException exception, on the second cycle, as its not possible to resend a response.

I suggest that instead of trying to send each title pair one at a time, that you display them all (or some if there are too many) on one JSP with a yes button next to each pair and as the user clicks the yes button an AJAX call is made to another servlet that updates the database (or an array to latter be used to update the database).

There are some good tutorial about using AJAX and JSP here of SOF and in YouTube.

Comment: Thanks for replying Alex. The list is a ResultSet from a query so it works fine and the Map is a HashMap that contains a list of the titles I want to compare to. And yes, I'm having java.lang.IllegalStateException exception

Comment: You will need to keep track of where you are in the Map so that when you return to the servlet you can go to the next element. This can be done by maintaining an index in a session variable and updating its value by one everytime you send the title pair to the client and then when you return to the servlet you can retrive its value and get the next value in the Map. Remove the while loop this will is not the solution, as everytime you enter the servlet it will reset to the first element.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I used an approach somehow similar by having all the pairs displayed in an JSP page with option for the user to confirm. The JSP has a form that call another Servlet to update the DB and display confirmation page.